# Pull image from private Docker registry in SaltStack

Tags: docker, salt-stack, docker-registry

I want to pull an image from a private Docker registry running on port 5000. It looks like SaltStack's dockerng module isn't liking the image format:

```
my service:
  dockerng.running:
    - name: some-service
    - image: docker-registry.example.com:5000/path/to/image
```

Results in this error when applying the state:

```
      ID: my service
Function: dockerng.running
    Name: some-service
  Result: False
 Comment: Failed to pull docker-registry.example.com:5000/path/to/image: Error 500: {"message":"invalid tag format"}
 Started: 15:30:57.202009
Duration: 24.922 ms
```

It works fine if I do this from the command line: `docker pull docker-registry.example.com:5000/path/to/image`. No username/password are required.

Any hints on how to get the state file in the correct format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a quick glance at [the source code](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/v2016.11.2/salt/modules/dockerng.py#L908), it seems that Salt will simply assume everything following the rightmost `:` character to be the image tag (so, in this case, `5000/path/to/image`, which is obviously a bad tag name).

A quick workaround seems to be to just explicitly specify a tag, instead of implicitly using `latest`:

```
my service:
  dockerng.running:
    - name: some-service
    - image: docker-registry.example.com:5000/path/to/image:latest
```